# Android. immortal Thread

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, service

Как известно, система может убить сервис (Service), если ей будет не хватать памяти. Но в наших силах сделать так, чтобы наш сервис ожил, когда проблема с памятью будет устранена. Делается это в методе `onStartCommand` возвращением соответствующей константы.

В своем приложении, к сожалению, я НЕ могу использовать сервис. Я использую обычный поток.

```
@Override
public void run() {       
    Looper.prepare();
    // code
    Looper.loop();
}
```

Он так же как сервис работает в фоновом режиме и выполняет соответствующие команды, но так же и падает при нехватке памяти.

Ну так вот, знает кто, есть ли возможность этого избежать? Или каким-нибудь образом реализовывать логику немедленного восстановления убитого потока?
Пробовал повышать приоритет у потока, так же прописывал в манифесте

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Не помогает.

Другой сервис использовать для поддержания потока так же нельзя =)
Все что приходит на ум - использовать какой-нибудь системный receiver, который можно прописать в манифесте. При этом он должен принимать команды постоянно, хотя бы раз в минуту.

Comment: Если не изменяет память, то в андроиде таки есть системное событие по смене минут. Рассылается каждую минуту. Думаю, вам оно должно подойти.

Comment: Ещё, можно рассылать свои собственные события чрез любой промежуток времени чрез `AlarmManager`

Comment: Не путайте потоки и сервис, это абсалютно разные вещи. И сервисы работают в ui потоке

Comment: @MrFirst никто и не путает, я знаю что служба работает в главном потоке, вопрос состоял совершенно не в этом.

Comment: Просто непонятно как андроид может убить поток который работает в процессе приложения при открытом же приложении

Comment: В рамках процесса высвобождением памяти занимается GC, а андроид может грохнутвесь процесс если он залочен больше 5с или нехватка памяти, если активити процесса в onStop, или я что то путаю. Попробуйте asynkTask, возможно вы не правильно работаете с Thread

Comment: @MrFirst я не говорил что приложение открыто) в том то и дело, что мне необходимо реализовать некий фоновый процесс аналогичный сервису, но им не являющийся.

Comment: его реализация как раз описана выше, не хватает только логики самовозрождения потока.

Comment: Тоесть вы хотите сделать самописный service?

Comment: У вас это не получится.

Comment: @ГомзяковВладимир А можете объяснить причину по который Вы НЕ можете использовать сервис? Мне просто никаких адекватных предположений в голову не приходит.

Comment: @xkor, совершенно верно. Я это помянул в ответе)

Comment: @xkor если без уточнений - так потому, что сервис палится через приложения-запущенные, еще его там можно грохнуть.
Фоновый поток же так не увидеть. 
а так как мое приложение является, скажем, приложением удаленного информирования - лишнее внимание пользователя ни к чему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вам может помочь только рассылка собственных `Intent` через `AlarmManager`. Эти интенты принимайте в собственном ресивере и запускайте сервис.

Вариант с системным [интентом](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK), рассылаемым каждую минуту, не подойдёт, т.к. его нельзя ловить в ресивере, определённом в манифесте. Только через `Context.registerReceiver()`. А, значит, нужен кто-то работающий, чтоб среагировать на интент.

Comment: AlarmManager отлично подошел для решения этой проблемы. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @ГомзяковВладимир, всегда пожалуйста) И, если ответ решил вашу проблему, то вы можете проголосовать за него и отметить его "верным". Для этого используются стрелочка вверх и галочка слева от тела ответа)

Comment: а есть какая возможность отследить момент крушения потока, и в этом самом моменте и реализовывать методы по восстановлению потока, а не спамить AlarmManager в рессивер каждую минуту?

Comment: @ГомзяковВладимир, ну... Если поток при завершении системой выкидывает исключение какое-нить, типа `InterrupedException`, то его можно отловить попробовать переопределённым отлавливателем ошибок и в нём либо запустить заново поток, либо запланировать это через `AlarmManager`

Comment: Попытался отловить исключение - безрезультатно. Метод finalize() так же не вызывается. Есть какие еще идеи?)

Comment: Не знаю, зачем тут `finalize`... Когда сиситема прибивает ваш поток он какое нибудь исключение бросает вообще или тишина?..

Comment: вообще тишина...